# Making HTTP requests in PHP without third party libraries

Tags: php, http

I'd like to make `DELETE`, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` requests in PHP without requiring a third party library like cURL.

Any tip?

Comment: I think this is why there is cURL for php, must host support it. You can do GET with the file_get_contents() function i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use [fsockopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php):

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

An easier way than constructing your HTTP request yourself using `fsockopen` is using the standard [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) function:

```
$fh = fopen('http://example.com', 'r');
while  (!feof($fh)) {
    $content .= fread($fh, 8192);
}
fclose($fh);
```

You can then make more complex requests (e.g. `POST`) using [`stream_context_create`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), which can be passed to `fopen` as an argument:

```
$querystring = http_build_query(array(
    'name' => 'SomeName',
    'password' => 'SomePassword'
));
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $querystring
    )
));

$fh = fopen('http://example.com', 'r', false, $context);
// the request will be a POST
```

Comment: Thanks, and can I append the parameters for the POST request to the querystring? For example, http://example.com/saveUser?name=SomeName&password=SomePassword ?

Comment: @Marco See edit and, for other options you can add, [HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

While fopen and fsockopen certainly works, another option is to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents). With file_get_contents, you don't have to worry about how to read the data. A GET example is just a single call, like:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

To issue a PUT request, send a context created with [stream_context_create](http://php.net/stream_context_create) to the third parameter, like:

```
// Create stream
$headers = array(
  "http" => array(
    "method" => "PUT"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($headers);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```